# How to change the base URL of a blazor wasm app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

The generated template for a blazor wasm hosted app has its base URL starting at '/' ( ie, `https://localhost:5001/` for local development or `https://www.domain-name.xyz/` when deployed.) I need this base URL to be '/app' instead, ie, (`https://localhost:5001/app`) or (`https://www.domain-name.xyz/app`).

The documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) says that I have to change the base URL in the `<base />` tag in index.html:

`<base href="/app/" />`

and use the command line argument `--pathbase` when developing locally:

`dotnet run --pathbase=/app`

I did that and changed nothing else to the template.
This however does not work for me. I just get a 404 not found for all the files of the app.

This issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22943) says that I also need to change where the Blazor files are exposed by passing '/app' to UseBlazorFrameworkFiles:

`app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/app")`

This also does not solve my problem.

Can anyone provide a step by step guidance to how to achieve this and that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're almost there.  I'm not sure what you're doing with the root site so I've added a simple landing page with a link to the WASM SPA.  Here's a full set on instructions.

1. *host.html* - change base to `<base href="/app/" />`.  This will make sure all the `@Page` directives in the SPA get prefixed with *app*.  You need the trailing `/`.
2. *host.html* - change the script reference to `<script src="/app/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>`.  You'll get away with not changing it if you're hosting a single WASM SPA.  Experiment.
3. WASM Project file Add `StaticWebAssetBasePath`.  This sets up the build with the correct path.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath>app</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

3. Update `Startup` in the Server project, adding a new middleware path for *mywebsite/app*

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();


    app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/app"), first =>
    {
        first.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/app");
        first.UseStaticFiles();

        first.UseRouting();
        first.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("app/{*path:nonfile}", "app/index.html");
        });
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        // endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("_index.cshtml");
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Index");
    });
}
```

I've added a default landing page to the root site - *_Index.cshtml*

```
@page "/"
@model WebApplication2.Server.Pages._IndexModel
    <h3>Hello App</h3>
<div><a href="/app">App WASM SPA</a></div>
@{
}
```

Note FetchData won't work until you update the controller url

```
forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("/WeatherForecast");
```

You can also move the WASM *wwwroot* into the root and add the startup page at say _App.cshtml to launch the SPA.

For more information there's a Github site [here by Javier Nelson](https://github.com/javiercn/BlazorMultipleApps/) and an article I wrote on how to host multiple SPAs on the same website [here](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Hydra%20Full%20Article.html) with a Github Repo.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It works like a charm when run locally with `dotnet run` command. But when dockerized, I see the requests twice: one with the correct path (`localhost/app/{ressourse}`) which results in a 200OK response, and one with the path `localhost/app/app/{ressource}` which results in a 404 response. Any chance you know why I'm having that?

Comment: Straight answer is no, I don't user Docker.  Over to the community - I suspect it's in the proxy'ing. All my stuff goes up to Azure App Services.

Comment: I finally figured out why I was having more requests (
erroneous requests) than I should have. It is because my app is a PWA. When publishing the pwa app, dotnet generates a file called service-worker-assets.js that contains the list of all needed files to make the app work offline. Apparently, changing the base path of the app breaks this mechanism. I fixed that by removing the "app/" part (which is my base path) from the paths of all files in service-worker-assets.js (`sed -i 's/app\\\///g' wwwroot/app/service-worker-assets.js`). I might open an issue on that later. Thanks again.

Comment: In my case I also had to add `app.UseStaticFiles("/app");`. This resolved issues with Blazorise and potentially third-party libraries that add other static files to a wasm path.